# Can I directly connect a GPIO OUTPUT and INPUT

Tags: raspberry-pi

Can I directly connect a GPIO OUTPUT and INPUT of a raspberry pi? I heard that this would be dangerous in case that both GPIOs are accidentally set as outputs and that it is better to put a resistor of at least 220 ohm in between (not to ground?). Is this really necesarry?